# On `ContinuedFraction`

Tags: functions, implementation-details

The code

```
p = Integrate[E^-x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
p // ContinuedFraction
```

produces

[image]

Does this mean that

(i) Mathematica knows that a terminating or periodic continued fraction expansion for `p` does not exist

or

(ii) Mathematica does not actually know whether a terminating or periodic continued fraction expansion for `p` exists?

Comment: `p // N // ContinuedFraction`  works.

Comment: or `p // ContinuedFraction[[#, 30]] &`

Comment: @BillWatts : Thank you for your comments. However, my interest is precisely whether a terminating or periodic continued fraction expansion for `p` exists.

Comment: Equivalently, is sqrt(pi)*erf(1) a square root of a rational.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau : Thank you for your comment. Rather, the question is as to whether Mathematica knows if `p` is rational or a **quadratic irrational** or a **non-quadratic irrational**.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: As you want to know whether a terminating or periodic continued fraction expansion exists (your comment to @BillWatts), you should approach this mathematically, not with M's ContinuedFraction function. Terminating cf expansions exist only for rational numbers. Periodic cf fraction expansions exist only for algebraic numbers, not for transcendentals. You should figure out if Sqrt@Pi Exp@1 is transcendental. If it is, then the cf expansion can be neither terminating nor periodic.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: As to your question whether or not M *knows* something, that is also in general impossible to answer. *If* M knows it's an algebraic number *then* it will return a periodic cf, that much is guaranteed. But for M to *always detect* that a number is algebraic is not documented. I deem it possible that a number is algebraic and M can not determine that (you said "knows").

Comment: @AndreasLauschke : Thank you for your comments. The reason for my question was Mathematica's quoted message that the number `p` "does not have a terminating or periodic continued fraction expansion"; I was wondering if Mathematica was meaning what it was saying, or something else was going on. I actually doubt that such a determination can be done algorithmically.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: My guess is that ContinuedFraction looks at a few million terms in the cf expansion and then looks for periods. These term calculations can be done very fast, it's a relatively simple recursion involving fast operations such as Mod, which is incredibly fast as a machine instruction. And then it doesn't find any, calls it a day and gives that error message. A better error message then would be something like "in ... million terms no period could be found, therefore it is assumed ... is transcendental; specify an explicit number of terms ..."

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Strictly speaking, if someone says there is *positively* no period in this non-terminating cf, then he is indirectly saying that the number is transcendental. ContinuedFraction can not possibly do a strict and reliable check, because ContinuedFraction[Pi+E] returns the same error message, and whether or not Pi+e is rational remains an open question in advanced  math. People don't even have an *idea* on how to approach this. *If* the number is (positively known to be) transcendental, a better error message would be something like "... is transcendental, and therefore no ...".

Comment: @IosifPinelis: With that said, when M *does* know it's an algebraic number, it computes the period quite efficiently. I realize this is not your question. I suspect that the input is parsed, and if a surd is detected, it goes into a "process as algebraic number" branch. For example, the immensely practical ContinuedFraction@Sqrt@410286423278424567//Short gives you a 7.8 million terms period. But you gave it the information that it's an algebraic number, because you have gave it a Sqrt in the input. Notice that the last term in the period is twice the first term, which I can't explain here.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke : Good points, especially with `ContinuedFraction[Pi+E]`. Thank you for these further comments.

Comment: `QuadraticIrrationalQ[p]` finishes a little bit faster than `ContinuedFraction[p]`, so maybe it using that.

Comment: @Goofy : Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I have just been informed by Wolfram Support that

> The developers in charge of this functionality inform me that ContinuedFraction does a structural check on its first argument, using a number of heuristic tests which do not constitute a proof.

This confirms the [observation by Andreas Lauschke](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295526/on-continuedfraction?noredirect=1#comment731780_295526) that "ContinuedFraction[Pi+E] returns the same error message", whereas whether $\pi+e$ is rational is a known open question.

Comment: Furthermore, this message only refers to *fixed* periods. Not all periods are *fixed* periods. For example, ContinuedFraction[E] returns that error message too, although the cf expansion clearly has a period: E as a regular continued fraction is {2,{1,2k+2,1}} as you can see easily with ContinuedFraction[E,30]. But E does indeed not have a *fixed* period, because it is transcendental and not algebraic.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke : Thank you for your latter comment as well.